# mongodb not letting writes go through

Tags: mongodb, groovy

Writing to Mongodb via Java Driver.  Getting the following error:

```
com.mongodb.WriteConcernException: { "serverUsed" : "127.0.0.1:27017" , "err" : "_a != -1" , "n" : 0 , "connectionId" : 3 , "ok" : 1.0}
at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getWriteException(CommandResult.java:90)
at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:79)
at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:131)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector._checkWriteError(DBTCPConnector.java:135)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.access$000(DBTCPConnector.java:39)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$1.execute(DBTCPConnector.java:186)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$1.execute(DBTCPConnector.java:181)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.doOperation(DBTCPConnector.java:210)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:181)
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insertWithWriteProtocol(DBCollectionImpl.java:528)
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insert(DBCollectionImpl.java:193)
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insert(DBCollectionImpl.java:165)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:161)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:147)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection$insert.call(Unknown Source)
```

Can't find any reference in docs to `"err" : "_a != -1"`.  Any thoughts?

EDIT:

Adding code I used (not all as it relies on other libraries to parse files):

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient()
mongoClient.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.SAFE)
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("vcf")
List<DBObject> documents = new ArrayList<DBObject>()
DBCollection recordsColl = db.getCollection("records")
//loop through file
BasicDBObject mongoRecord = new BasicDBObject()
//add data to mongoRecord
documents.add(mongoRecord)
//end loop
recordsColl.insert(documents)
mongoClient.close()
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you used to generate this error?

Comment: Just not even sure what this error is even referencing

Comment: Is the err (_a != -1) found anywhere in the data your writing?

Comment: No, never using _a.  Found this in the server log: `Tue Aug 19 10:03:20.444 [conn3]  mydb.records Assertion failure _a != -1 src/mongo/db/ops/../pdfile.h 605`

Comment: Perfect, thats better. It looks like the _a is being asserted and is not the same type as its evaluation. In this case, the -1.

Comment: Hmmm, any way of going about where the assertion is happening?  I have indexes but they aren't forcing any value.